# thread does not end/timeout

Tags: python, multithreading, sleep

in general I try to solve a simple problem.
I try to access a website and if an error (exception) occurs it should give another try after a delay period. the whole code is embedded in an infinite loop, if this might be a problem. my first try was something like this:

```
while 1 == 1
  connected = False
    while not connected:
        try:
            br.follow_link(l)
            connected = True
        except:
            time.sleep(61)
```

But everytime an exception occurs the freezes and time.sleep(61) never ended.
I read something about threads, and implemented the following:

```
def sleeper(sec):
    time.sleep(sec)

while 1 == 1
  connected = False
    while not connected:
        try:
            br.follow_link(l)
            connected = True
        except:
            t = Thread(target=sleeper, args=(61,))
            t.start()
            t.join(62)
```

So basically the same concept, but this time t.join(62) never terminates, even with the timeout of 62secs. So I am a little bit lost here, because a cant solve my simple problem. do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So, I wrote small test python script, and everything works as expected:

```
import threading
import time

class MyException(Exception):
    pass


def sleeper(sec):
    print "In thread"
    time.sleep(sec)

def follow_link():
    raise MyException("My Error")


while True:
    connected = False
    while not connected:
        try:
            follow_link()
            connected = True
        except Exception, e:
            print e
            t = threading.Thread(target=sleeper, args=(5,))
            t.start()
            t.join(7)
```

But I think about that this does de facto same thing as your first example code, because (as I see in debugger) t.join freezes execution too.